# Show the correct amount of input field based on qty input field entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to arrange a setup where the amount of Attendee input fields display based on the amount of qty entered.

Example will be the Attendee 1 field will always display as it is a required field to fill in. Then if the user enters "2" in the qty input field only Attendee 1 & Attendee 2 will display and so on...max attendee is 15.

I have set up the html mark up here.

```
<div id="personal-fields">
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 1<span class="validate">*</span></label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee1" required="" /><p class="not-validated">* This field is required.</p>
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 2</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee2" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 3</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee3" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 4</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee4" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 5</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 6</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee6" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 7</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee7" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 8</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee8" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 9</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee9" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 10</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee10" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 11</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee11" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 12</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee12" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 13</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee13" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 14</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee14" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 15</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee15" />
</div>

<div class="attributeselection">
<span class="leftselection thumbnail">Qty<input name="ctl00$MainCentre$container$container$Content_31$StyleDetail1$txtQuantity" id="ctl00_MainCentre_container_container_Content_31_StyleDetail1_txtQuantity" value="1" maxlength="5" class="inputqty form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return NumericText(event);" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text"> 
</span> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjy4hdhz/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a question? What problem are you encountering? Is there some reason you couldn't set up the code here in Stack Overflow as a code snippet? So, you just want us to write all the JavaScript for you?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes I would appreciate if someone could please help me set up the script based on the details above as that is out of my capability. Or give me a starting point where I can try attempt to figure it out? Thanks

Comment: That's really not how Stack Overflow works. We are not a code writing service. "Stack Overflow" is literally a type of error you can encounter in programming. The site is meant for people to post specific programming problems they have, not to just ask for code to be written to solve a use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using JS. I wrapped your label/input in an element so they're easier to target, and added a class that toggles the `display` property to hide/show them.

```js
var field = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainCentre_container_container_Content_31_StyleDetail1_txtQuantity'),
  groups = document.getElementById('personal-fields').getElementsByClassName('group');
    
field.addEventListener('change',function() {
 var val = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
   if (i < val) {
      groups[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
     groups[i].classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#personal-fields {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding: 20px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }
 #personal-fields label{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 .personal-field-value{
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  display: block;
 }
 .personal-field-value:hover{
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 span.validate{
  color: #d10000;
  vertical-align: top;
 }
 p.not-validated{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #d10000 !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: none;
 }
  
  .attributeselection{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  .attributeselection input{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="personal-fields">
    <div class="group">
    <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 1<span class="validate">*</span></label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee1" required="" /><p class="not-validated">* This field is required.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="group hidden">
           <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 2</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee2" />

    </div>
    <div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 3</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee3" />

    </div>
    <div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 4</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee4" />

    </div>
    <div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 5</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 6</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 7</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 8</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 9</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 10</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 11</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 12</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 13</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 14</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
<div class="group hidden">
        <label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 15</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />

    </div>
       
</div>

<div class="attributeselection">
<span class="leftselection thumbnail"><input name="ctl00$MainCentre$container$container$Content_31$StyleDetail1$txtQuantity" id="ctl00_MainCentre_container_container_Content_31_StyleDetail1_txtQuantity" value="1" maxlength="5" class="inputqty form-control" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]*" type="text"></span> 
         <span class="rightselection thumbnail"><span id="ctl00_MainCentre_container_container_Content_31_StyleDetail1_lblSelection"></span></span> 
      </div>
```

Comment: Nice - i was just working on this exct approach - yuouu got there first :)

Comment: @Michael Coker this is perfect! thanks so much however it only let me reach 5 attendees even if i type 6 - 15 in the qty field?

Comment: @Jc0807 you're welcome. I only copied and pasted like 5 of your inputs :) I'll add more in just a sec, but you can add as many as you want. I have to write new html to add them (to add the parent element) so I stopped at 5 ;)

Comment: @Jc0807 ok added 5 more.

Comment: @Jc0807 added all 15

Comment: Thanks again @MichaelCoker it works perfectly fine however when I try to apply it to the working site it stops working, strange!

Comment: Never mind @MichaelCoker i got it working by adding jq(document).ready(function(){ before the code. Thanks again !

Comment: @Jc0807 awesome no problem :)

Comment: Hey @MichaelCoker 1 last assistance please, how can I make it that if 3 attendee input is shown then only those 3 input fields need to be filled? Current setup is that all attendee fields are required and are only "hidden" there for it won't allow me to continue to next step essentially those other 9 fields are not filled in. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: @Jc0807 I don't see anything in your code that makes the input fields required.

Comment: @MichaelCoker its on the first field. <span class="validate">*</span> and also this part required="" /><p class="not-validated">* This field is required.</p>

Comment: @Jc0807 that's just a span and paragraph. How does that stop you from preventing the form? Do you have any JS for that?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`.slice()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) makes this pretty easy:

```js
$(".inputqty").change(function() {        // when the Quantity input is changed
  var qty = +this.value                   // (try to) convert its value to a number
  if (qty >= 1 && qty <= 15) {                             // if valid, then...
    $(".personal-field-title").hide().slice(0,qty).show()  // show that many labels
    $(".personal-field-value").hide().slice(0,qty).show()  // and inputs
  } else {                                                 // otherwise
    alert("Please enter a quantity between 1 and 15.")     // show message
  }
}).change()    // trigger the handler once to show default number of items
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="personal-fields">
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 1<span class="validate">*</span></label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee1" required="" /><p class="not-validated">* This field is required.</p>
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 2</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee2" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 3</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee3" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 4</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee4" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 5</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee5" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 6</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee6" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 7</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee7" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 8</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee8" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 9</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee9" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 10</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee10" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 11</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee11" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 12</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee12" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 13</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee13" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 14</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee14" />
<label class="personal-field-title">Attendee 15</label><input class="personal-field-value" name="attendee15" />
</div>

<div class="attributeselection">
<span class="leftselection thumbnail">Qty<input name="ctl00$MainCentre$container$container$Content_31$StyleDetail1$txtQuantity" id="ctl00_MainCentre_container_container_Content_31_StyleDetail1_txtQuantity" value="1" maxlength="5" class="inputqty form-control" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="/*return NumericText(event);*/" pattern="[0-9]*" type="number"> 
</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @nnnnnn, how can we adjust this to make it only show Attendee 1 label and field on default until the qty value is changed?

Comment: The code shown does that (as of my edit from several minutes ago). By the way, in my demo I changed your input to be `type="number"` to make it nicer for the user, and I commented out what the `onkeypress` was doing because you didn't show that function.